# Window snapping with dual monitors

Tags: multiple-monitors, windows-10, modern-ui-snapping

Is there a way to disable window snapping on borders and keeping the maximized window dragging?

I know how to disable the snapping, but it also disables the dragging for maximized windows. I was using W7 before and this feature was perfect. I have 2 monitors and dragging a window from a monitor to another is annoying because if the mouse is not fast enough when crossing, it gets stuck on the edge and won't go across unless I give it enough speed.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the layout of the monitors set correctly in Control Panel? i.e. are they right next to each other? If not, this could be causing you to have to move your mouse faster in order to "jump" the gap between your displays.

Comment: I do. 1 and 2 right by each others. 1 on left, 2 on right.